# I can get into a web directory by using web browser ,but file manager fails

Tags: server, ftp, browser, filemanager

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and firefox web browser

I need to get into the following web directory (for example)

http://dl3.fardasub.xyz/

I could get into the server and access its file system without any username or password

And then i tried to get into the same site through the file manager using ftp protocol (eg:- ftp://dl3.fardasub.xyz) and i chose the option "connect anonymously". But it failed.It requires username and password
what shuold i do to get into that directory. At least is there any way by using the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http and ftp are different protocols and are handled by different servers; the fact that this particular web server is configured to allow public access doesn't mean that its ftp "counterpart" is configured the same way.

You should check with your service provider or administrator what is the correct way to connect to the ftp server.